# Using OrderBy() in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to modify a collection so that I can sort the sequence of items in it.

So I am doing something like:

```
IEnumerable<ItemType> ordered = myItems.OrderBy( (item) => item.Age);
```

However, I want to modify the `myItems` collection itself to have the ordered sequence... is it possible?

I want something like:

```
myItems.SomeActionHere // This should modify myItems in place.
```

This might be a newbie or noob question. Sorry about that.

Comment: `myItems = myItems.OrderBy(i => i.Age)`?

Comment: myItems is of type ReadOnlyCollection<ItemType>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it's an array you can use [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx).  This performs an in-place sort without duplicating references/values.

Equally, however, you can just tag `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` to the end of your linq statement to 'realise' the ordered enumerable if duplicating references is not an issue (normally it isn't).

E.g:

```
myItems = myItems.OrderBy(i => i.Age).ToArray();
```

If you absolutely need it back as another `ReadOnlyCollection` instance - you could do this:

```
myItems = new ReadOnlyCollection<ItemType>(myItems.OrderBy(i => i.Age).ToArray());
```

Note that `.ToArray()` works because arrays implement `IList<T>` even though they're not modifiable.

Alternatively - there's also [Array.AsReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53kysx7b.aspx) - to turn it on it's head:

```
myItems = Array.AsReadOnly(myItems.OrderBy(i => i.Age).ToArray());
```

Apart from being a shorter line of code I don't see much benefit - unless reducing angle-brackets is important to you :)

Comment: @Andras...thats even better. A shorter line of code in my code is always welcome. I didnt even know that there was an Array.AsReadOnly(). I have no idea how you guys looks up this stuff...

Comment: Reducing Angle Brackets? What does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use Linq to order your collection i place. Unless you go specifically go and implement `OrderBy` for your sequence type.

Answer (score 0):

`OrderBy` (like most other Linq operators) is *lazy*; it doesn't materialize its results, it just re-reads the source collection every time. So if you change the content of `myItems`, every time you will enumerate `ordered` you will see the latest changes in `myItems`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) or convert to a [SortedList](https://stackoverflow.com/q/981992/503761).