# How does C# SortedList internally work?

Tags: c#, list, sortedlist

I was wondering, how does the `SortedList` work.
I know that a regular `List` is based on a dynamic array, but what is `SortedList` based on?

And what sorting algorithm it uses?

Thanks

Comment: This is the sort of thing where you should either examine the source code proper or use a decompiler to see how it's implemented.  The question is a poor fit for SO.

Comment: or just look up the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @ps2goat, sure, if you want a paraphrasing. :)

Comment: It doesn't say what it is based on and how it works

Comment: @KirkWoll, MS does tend to throw bits and pieces all over the place!

Answer (score 3):

`SortedList` class source code can be found [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/sortedlist.cs).

According to this source, `SortedList` keeps data in two plain arrays of keys and values:

```
private TKey[] keys;
private TValue[] values;
```

Sort order is maintained on the array of keys. When a new item (key/value pair) is added, `SortedList` first finds proper index in the sorted array of keys (using `Array.BinarySearch`), then moves partial contents of **both** key and value arrays (using `Array.Copy`) starting from this index upward to create a gap where both key and value are inserted. Likewise, when an item is deleted by its key, `SortedList` searches for the item's index in the array of keys, then moves partial contents of both arrays from this index downward to close the gap.

So, one thing to keep in mind is that when adding to or deleting from a large `SortedList`, a lot of data may be moved around. On the positive side, retrieving items by index is always fast regardless of the list size.

Answer (score 2):

From the sortedlist documentation: "SortedList is implemented as an array of key/value pairs, sorted by the key."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7a8xew6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If you use the default constructor (no parameters): "Initializes a new instance of the SortedList class that is empty, has the default initial capacity, and is sorted according to the IComparable interface implemented by each key added to the SortedList object."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxb97few%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Or you can pass a custom comparer:

Initializes a new instance of the SortedList class that is empty, has the default initial capacity, and is sorted according to the specified IComparer interface.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7a8xew6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Other constructor options:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.SortedList.SortedList%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

How to use IComparer interface:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the internals of how it works, get yourself any half decent decompiler, such as .Net Reflector.

A quick look shows that internally, SortedList maintains it's sorted state by keeping an internal array sorted at all times. When an item is added using the Add Method, it uses a binary search on the keys to identify the correct index to insert the new item.

Comment: No need for a decompiler; the source code in C# can be downloaded from Microsoft's web site with a little searching.

Answer (score 0):

A `SortedList` is an object that maintain's two array to store the element's of the list.

One array store's the `Key` and the other array store's its associated `values`.

The element's in the SortedList are sorted  either according to a specific [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implementation specified when the SortedList is created or according to the [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implementation provided by the keys themselves. They cannot contain duplicate keys.

Whenever any element is added or removed the index is adjusted accordingly as a result operations related to `SortedList` are slower.